# How to use axios response data in data function - vue

Tags: vue.js, axios

Using axios to fetch api data:

```
fetchData () {
  axios.get(globalConfig.OFFERS_URL)
    .then((resp) => {
      this.offersData = resp.data
      console.log(resp)
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log(err)
    })
}
```

Data function:

```
  data () {
    return {
      offersData: {}
    }
  }
```

Now i can use fetched data in my template, like so: `{{ offersData.item[0].id }}`

But can i set the fetched data in a data function:

```
  data () {
    return {
      offersData: {},
      id: this.offersData.item[0].id
    }
  }
```

It's not working for me, is that even possible to store axios get's response in a data function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably are looking for computed property:

```
data () {
  return {
    offersData: {},
  }
},
computed() {
  id() {
    return this.offersData.item && this.offersData.item[0].id;
  }
}
```

As for data function, it is used to define shape of state (set up the properties to be tracked) of component and give valid initial values to it. In this case, however, `id` should neither be a part of state (it's always a part of `offersData` value, after all) nor its initial value can be calculated before `offersData` is set up by a remote call.

Comment: That return statement will cause an error because `this.offersData.item` is `undefined` when the component initializes. And `this.offersData` will always be truthy in that context. I'd do `if (this.offersData.item && this.offersData.item[0]) { return this.offersData.item[0].id }`

Comment: Ah, missed that part out, thank you. I made a shortcut here, as `this.offersData.item` is undefined initially, and can be only set up by a call returning an array - so if it fails, it fails for a reason.

Comment: Thanks, as i understand `data ()` is for static values and `v-model`, right? Also why do you set `this.offersData.item &&` before id? Still can't get it.

Comment: Because initial value of `this.offersData` is an empty object - and when `id()` is called the first time, attempt to check the whole path results in error (attempt to access property `0` of `undefined`). This way, the check is avoided with so-called [short-circuit evaluation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation) - id is `undefined` until filled, no error thrown.

Comment: Thanks for explanation, also can't i use computed methods inside methods? or it's just for templates?

Comment: Yes, you can, but as properties, not as methods (i.e., you should write `this.id`, not `this.id()`)